# How to use void to delete id not return to another URL Page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/user_cart/remove/", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.DELETE})
public void removeData(Long id) {
    userReqDetailService.removeByID(id);

}
```

When i try to use like this if always return to another url (http://localhost:8082/user_cart/remove/?id=163)
and error massage to spring ( template: "class path resource [templates/user_cart/remove.html]") )

I just want to delete data by id and don't want to return to another page url

Comment: Using GET as a delete is a very b ad idea... If this is a public facing website, one scan by google and poof... But this is a regular method in an `@Controller` use an `@RestController` or place an `@ResponseBody` on the method to prevent a page from rendering.

Comment: But When I use @ResponseBody is return error the same brother ...? and how can i change i just need only delete dont' need to return to another page brother ?

Comment: I doubt it is doing the same. It won't forward to a new page it will just return a HTTP 200. Also if you navigate to the URL (which is what you seem to be doing) you will obviously go to this page.

Comment: this one I use with controller for btn_delete on Thymleaf brother

Comment: Firstly I'm not your brother so stop calling me that, next I have now idea what you are using it with in thymeleaf. I suspect a form submit which will **always** take you there. If you don't you need to do an ajax post of the form instead of a regular form.

Answer (score 0):

Add **@ResponseBody** on method **removeData**.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/user_cart/remove/", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.DELETE})
@ResponseBody
public void removeData(Long id) {...}
```

Comment: @RequestMapping(value ="/user_cart/remove/", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.DELETE})
 @ResponseBody
 public void removeData(Long id) {
  
  userReqDetailService.removeByID(id);
  
 }

but i still return ot another URL

Comment: http://localhost:8082/user_cart/remove/?id=161

when i click btn delete is return to this URL